# How do we draw a curve between outlines / boundaries in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I want to draw dotted curve between the boundaries. For eg, consider the following image:

[image]

From the image, I have the dark outline - what I want is the dotted part through code. As of now, I have the following algorithm:

1. For each point say A, find it's two nearest points
2. Form these two points, find it's slope, and then the slope of the line perpendicular to it.
3. The using the perpendicular slope and point A, determine the line and also where it intersects the parallel point, say B
4. Draw a point half way between A and B on this perpendicular line.

This method is like Brute force. I think using numpy, opencv or plotting libraries, this might be a trivial thing. Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: If you create a mask where it's white inside each shape and black outside, then you can "skeletonize" the masks. OpenCV does not have a skeletonize function as far as I know, but scikit-image [does](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_skeleton.html).

Comment: Actually, OpenCV *does* have a thinning algorithm, but it's in the contrib modules: https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d2d/group__ximgproc.html#ga37002c6ca80c978edb6ead5d6b39740c